# Java Number/Maths Abstraction

Tags: java, math, abstraction, bigdecimal

I'm currently in the process of writing an application that has quite a number of mathematically calculations in it. In some situations, these calculations need to be done quickly and we can deal with a small amount of precision loss to get the maths done as fast as possible. On the other hand, sometimes we require that the calculations be done very precisely (and there are use cases for in between, where we would implement our own way of doing multiplication/division/addition/subtraction/power etc that is more precise that float * float (or double * double, I am aware that float is a bad choice), but faster than BigDecimal.multiply(BigDecimal)... or even something like apfloat rather than BigDecimal).

Are there any existing libraries that allow an abstraction of such number formats, so that different ways of doing the maths are abstracted away, or do I have to create my own?

I've started coding up something, which seems to be working *okay*, but it would be far better to have a nicely tested library rather than reinventing the wheel I think.

**EDITED to clarify the situation with content from a comment below:**

The problem is that BigDecimal is significantly slower than double * double etc. We need to be able to switch between precision and speed. The reasoning behind this is that we need to be able to run fast tests for debugging and cross checks with real world data (which does not need to be perfectly accurate), but the final simulation (which will often take days to weeks: unacceptable for debugging) will require high precision. Thus the need to be able to switch at will.

Comment: What's your problem with apfloat?

Comment: We need to be able to switch between super high speed and high precision. Our application will run for days to weeks at a time, which is unacceptable for simple tests (that don't require high precision). For more info, see my comment to Peter Lawrey below.

Comment: I don't know any arbitrary precision library for java that is faster than [apfloat](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/)... Or even any such lib for java that uses floating point numbers. A workaround is to use integers, than you can use [JScience](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html), and later divide by the scale.

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be arbitrary precision. We only need about 5-10 points of precision, but they MUST be guaranteed to be perfectly accurate. Ideally, I'd like a fixed point library, but that's not the topic of the question. The topic of the question is an abstraction library that allows changing between arbitrary precision/fixed point/native calculation methods (or even variations thereof).

Comment: Well I don't know such a library, but of course it doesn't mean that none exists. (But if really none exists, you could implement it for yourself with a strategy pattern e.g., though it reduces performance a bit)

Comment: That's exactly where I'm headed at the moment, and I've also decided to open source it when I'm done. It will basically be a wrapper around `BigDecimal`/`BigInteger` functionality, but with the ability to implement other strategies for doing things like (currently implemented) `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, `divide` and `pow` with a factory for creating new number/math objects.

Comment: Hi Ricky, I just run in the same problem - how did your efforts go back then in 2011? :)

Comment: I can't remember, sorry. I think we just ended up having to make the simulations faster by cutting corners and making (sometimes incorrect) assumptions, rather than actually doing the maths (only in tests of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`double` has more than twice the precision as `float` and is typically no more than 10% slower. IMHO, there is a very rarely a good reason to use `float`, using `double` or `BigDecimal` is usually better.

Comment: I agree, on the double front. I started (stupidly) using floats and have been in the process of changing them all to double. The problem is that BigDecimal is significantly slower than double * double etc. We need to be able to switch between precision and speed. The reasoning behind this is that we need to be able to run fast tests for debugging and cross checks with real world data, but the final simulation (which will often take days to weeks: unacceptable for debugging) will require high precision. Thus the need to be able to switch at will.

Comment: That said, I did like your answer so if nothing better comes along, I will accept it.

Comment: Many operations only use `double` precision so using `float` is actually slower. Where `float` can have a small gain is in better use of the cache.  I agree that `BigDecimal` doesn't perform as well, but if you need more than 15 digits of precision it may be your only option.

Comment: Yeh, that's the point. Sometimes it's necessary, sometimes it's not. We need to be able to specify if we would like to sacrifice precision for speed, or speed for precision. I worked on my own abstraction library today. So far it seems to work quite well, and an implementation of calculations using `long` looks to be about 10x faster than `BigDecimal` when using JIT (though that could be my faulty benchmarking skills!), and on par with `BigDecimal` with the -Xint flag turned on. About 10% overhead when using a `BigDecimal` adapter.

Comment: Also, said library will be released Open Source, since there seems to be no equivalent (though it's fairly simple at the moment and only implements a small subset of operations- add,sub,mult,div,pow)

Comment: double doesn't guaratee even 2 points of precision in extreme cases. Well demonstrated in effective java item 48.

Comment: There are ways to abuse `double` but using `BigDecimal` may not do what you expect every time either. `new BigDecimal(0.1)` surprises some people.  In short, it helps to know what you are doing.

Comment: @david thus why as part of my maths implementation, I'm writing functions to handle calculations in longs, multiplying out the decimal (so 300.003 becomes 300003 until needed, when it is converted back). So far this method is on par with `BigDecimal` when JIT is not used, and faster by 10x when JIT is used. The only major drawback I can see is doing powers on values 100000 times larger than you expect will end up with a very very large number that may not fit in the long (the final value would, but intermittent calculation might not!) From my understanding, this is Fixed Point precision?

Comment: @PeterLawrey `new BigDecimal("0.1")` or `new BigDecimal("" + 0.1)`? :) I've never used `BigDecimal` before, but I always do quite a bit of research where my calculations are concerned for this project, and Unit Testing is... extensive, to say the least.

Comment: @FuzziBear, `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` is slightly more efficient.